# Union memory share in C

Tags: c, unions

Edit2: Can I do polymorphism with Union? It seems to me that I can change the data structure based on my need.

Edit: Fix the code. Use "." instead of "->". What I want to ask is, how to make sure the value is stored correctly when there's different data type (like int and char use interchangebly? Since both has different memory size, the one which needs bigger memory space would be allocate memory space for both types of variables to share.

Suppose I have 2 structs:

```
typedef struct a{
          int a;
}aType;

typedef struct b{
          char b;
}bType;

typedef union{
         aType a_type;
         bType b_type;
}ab;

int main(void){
         ab v1;
         v1.a_type.a = 5;
         v1.b_type.b = 'a'
}
```

As far as I know, both aType and bType will share the same memory. Since int has 3 bytes greater (int is 4 bytes, and char is 1 byte), it will have 4 memory blocks. The first one is the left most and the last one is the right most. The time I assign 'a' to variable b of v1, it will stay in the first block (the left most) of memory block. The value 5 still remains in the fourth block of memory (the right most).

Therefore, when prints it out, it will produce garbage value, won't it? If so, how to fix this problem? By this problem, which means if I store 'a' into b_type, the share memory must be sure to have that value 'a' only, not the previous integer value 5.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? How would you like it to work "right"?

Comment: Yes, you'll get a garbage value. But if you want to "fix" this, what is it that you want to happen? What value would you like to be printed?

Comment: Should be `v1.a_type.a`. the `->` syntax is for dereferencing a pointer and then accessing an element of it, but you are just accessing the element of the struct or union itself.

Comment: Which byte of `a` contains 5 (the "low bits") is implementation-defined.  That is, not portable.

Comment: If you don't want garbage values, don't use two members of a union at overlapping time.

Comment: What do you think it should produce?

(I'm not having a go at you, I'm just not entirely clear on the meaning of your question.)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all we should know if you're using a Big Endian od Little Endian processor.
Windows & Linux uses little endian format that means that the value 0x00000005 is actually written as 05-00-00-00, as if you write it right to left.
So, firs you put 5 into a part that means that the first byte is 05 and all the others are 00.
Than you place 'a' into b part you overwrite 05 with corresponding ascii value, that means 0x61.
When you look at the resulting number should be ... 97, that is the value of 0x61.

Alignment of union should start at the beginning, but byte order is platform dependent.
Qhat you told shoul de correct under Big Endian architecture, as Sun Solaris or any Risc processor.

Am I wrong?

HTH

Comment: OS has nothing to do with it. Endianness is entirely dependant on the CPU. Other than that, you're not wrong.

Comment: You're wrong in your statement that Windows and Linux use a little-endian format.  You're right about your application of the idea, though.  Endianness is controlled by the processor, not the OS.

Comment: Which means my problem is platform dependent? Is it ok if I assume things go right and do like that?

Comment: @Amumu - No, it's architecture dependent, but that's basically the same thing.  Whether it's OK or not depends on your audience and their computers.  If you control or otherwise know the architecture, it might be OK.  But be ready for weird bugs if someone tries to run it on an architecture with different endianness!  Make code that will either detect the architecture and respond accordingly, or that will issue an understandable error message if something's wrong.

Comment: @Amumu: Don't assume the byte order - check for it.

Comment: Ok, I talked about OS and it was wrong since linux could be installed on Risc processor too.
I have to say I've never seen Windows installed on a Risc (and I saw my last Solaris installed on Intel more than 10 years ago) so I'm quite used to match Endianness and OS while Endianness is CPU dependant...
Sorry...

Answer (score 7):

There is no right behavior. Setting a union via one member and retrieving a value from a different member causes undefined behavior. You can do useful things with this technique, but it is very hardware and compiler dependent. You will need to consider processor endianness and memory alignment requirements.

Back when I did almost all my programming in C, there were two (portable) techniques using unions that I relied on pretty heavily.

**A tagged union**. This is great when you need a dynamically typed variable. You set up a struct with two fields: a type discriminant and a union of all possible types.

```
struct variant {
  enum { INT, CHAR, FLOAT } type;
  union value {
    int i;
    char c;
    float f;
  };
};
```

You just had to be very careful to set the type value correctly whenever you changed the union's value and to retrieve only the value specified by the type.

**Generic pointers**. Since you can be pretty sure that all pointers have the same size and representation, you can create a union of pointer types and know that you can set and retrieve values interchangeably without regard to type:

```
typedef union {
  void *v;
  int* i;
  char* c;
  float* f;
} ptr;
```

This is especially useful for (de)serializing binary data:

```
// serialize
ptr *p;
p.v = ...; // set output buffer
*p.c++ = 'a';
*p.i++ = 12345;
*p.f++ = 3.14159;

// deserialize
ptr *p;
p.v = ...; // set input buffer
char c = *p.c++;
int i = *p.i++;
float f = *p.f++;
```

**FYI:** You can make your example simpler. The structs are unnecessary. You'll get the same behavior with this:

```
int main() {

  union {
    int a;
    char b;
  } v1;

  v1.a = 5;
  v1.b = 'a';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is really useful. But I didn't know all the pointers are the same size. You increase the pointer size by one block of memory (like *p.c++) is to move to the next pointer, and *p.v is the starting pointer for indexing, isn't it?

Comment: Pointers are the same size. What they point to may not be. The trick here is that you're incrementing a pointer of a specific type, so that the pointer moves on to the next item in the data stream (which may be a different type). So *p.c++ reads one char and increments the raw pointer value by sizeof(char). Then *p.i++ reads one int and increments the pointer by sizef(int). There is no "next pointer".

Comment: p.v is a void pointer type, which in C means that it can be set to point to anything without regard to type. That makes it useful for setting the initial value of the pointer, but any pointer type can be used to set the initial value if the types match or you cast them to the right pointer type.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you describe is platform/system/compiler dependent. On Intel x86 processors, for instance, the `5` is likely to be the first byte in the `int` for the `gcc` compiler.

The `union` interest comes from two main angles

- share the same space of memory in order to minimize the required memory allocation (in this case, the first byte [for instance] may indicate the type of the data in the structure/union).
- to analyze some data structure, without the need of using casting and pointers. For instance, a union between a `double` and a `char[8]` on some platforms is an easy way to get a per-char/byte view of the `double` structure.

If there is no benefit in using a `union`, don't do it.

Comment: So, can I do polymorphism with Union? It seems to me that I can change the data structure based on my need.

Comment: @Amumu Yes you can do polymorphism - but there is no *magic* in either Java or C++, the executable or JVM knows what kind of object it works with. If you want to emulate polymorphism, you could add a character at the beginning of your union(structures), set to 'A' for objectA and 'B' for objectB for instance. Then check in your executable which object you are dealing with, and there should be no object confusion (basically, you cannot guess if you have a `char` or an `int` by checking the first byte, if you allow any `int` value. E.g. on x86, first byte of "A" and the `int` 65 are equal...).

Comment: By using tag technique introduced in the other answer, I would not need to assign the name to my data type just to keep track. It would be useful. Thanks for clearing up my confusion.

Comment: +1, but the only guaranteed type that enables you to inspect all bytes of another data type is `unsigned char`. So to inspect a `double` you should use an `unsigned char[sizeof(double)]`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to fix this problem is by keeping track of what data you have stored. This is often done using a so-called tag member, like so:

```
struct mystructA {
    int data;
};
struct mystructB {
    char data;
};
enum data_tag {
    TAG_STRUCT_A,
    TAG_STRUCT_B
};
struct combined {
    enum data_tag tag;
    union {
        struct mystructA value_a;
        struct mystructA value_b;
    } data;
};
```

By keeping careful track of what data you put in, you can make sure only to read that same field later, thus ensuring you get a meaningful result.

Comment: I prefer the way it is done in SDL events, where each element in the union is a struct that shares the same first element, a tag that names what type it is. Same effect but with less levels of "dereferencing" looking syntax between you and your data.

Comment: Should I reset all the byte to zero before assign the char? Would it be simpler?
i.e. v1.aType.a = 0 then v1.bType.b = 'a'

Comment: @Null Set: the difference is that this code is valid, while putting a bunch of structs inside an union and expecting them to overlap isn't.

Comment: So, assigning value to different members of union will cause unpredictable behaviors, and should be avoided? The tag techniques is to keep track of what data member we already used for the union. However, what if someone else tries to assign value to the other variable in struct? Is there no way to prevent it?

Comment: @Jester: I was not aware that was the case. A well used library uses structs this way. I'm going to open a new question about it.

Comment: @Amumu, you do not need to reset other members before using a different one. And C assumes everyone plays nice and doesn't break the rules, so no, you can't prevent people from writing to the wrong element :) Write accessor functions that do sanity checks if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you access the union by the same element you last assigned to it with, there will be no problem. By accessing the char sized element of the union, the compiler makes sure to only return the bits you are interested in.

Edit: People were mentioning tagged unions. Here is another style of that, which SDL uses for their event struct.

```
enum union_tag {
    STRUCT_A,
    STRUCT_B
};

typedef struct {
    enum union_tag tag;
    int a;
} aType;

typedef struct {
    enum union_tag tag;
    char b;
} bType;

typedef union{
    enum union_tag tag;
    aType a_type;
    bType b_type;
} ab;
```

To access an element you would do something like this:

```
int result;

switch(my_union.tag){
    case STRUCT_A:
         result = my_union.a_type.a;
         break;
    case STRUCT_B:
         result = my_union.b_type.b;
         break;
}
```